# new server settings stopping duplicate email script from working

Tags: php, mysql, email

I have a simple form where I am trying to stop the same email from being entered twice and is a valid email. I had it working, but then transferred my site on to a new server now it stopped working.

Is there some configuration I need to change or look for on the new server to get this to work?

here is my code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $em = trim($_POST['email']);
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM survey_email WHERE email='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email'])."'") or die(mysql_error());
    $check = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);

    if($em === '' || !preg_match('/^.{1,62}@.{1,62}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/', $em) || $check > 0){
        $error = "Please enter a valid email";
    }else{
        $success = true;    
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO survey_email 
            (email) VALUES('".$_POST['email']."' ) ") 
            or die(mysql_error()); 
        header('Location: /survey-email-confirm.php');
    }
}
```

Comment: "now it stopped working" as in...? Computer set itself on fire? No effect? Blank screen?

Comment: Be aware that your code is *wide open* to SQL injection attacks.  It would be a good idea to read and understand this: http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should change

```
if($em === '' || !preg_match('/^.{1,62}@.{1,62}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/', $em) || $check > 0){
```

to

```
if($em === '' || !preg_match('/^.{1,62}@.{1,62}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/', $em) || $check){
```

since the value of $check would not be numeric.

Answer (score 0):

The below line returns an array, and you are checking array > 0,

```
$check = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
```

I guess you want to get number of rows to see if email already exists. Get it by:

```
$numRows = mysql_num_rows($sql);
```

Then use it in `IF` condition:

```
$numRows > 0
```